# Function doesn't use updated variable

Tags: python

when using an interactive mode (e.g. ipython), and creating the function interactively the following works nicely:

```
x = [1,2,3]

def main():
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# [1,2,3]
# > x = 1
# > main()
# 1
```

When using an IDE like pycharm and running this file 'with Python console', I'm able to set `x = 1`, but when calling `main()` again, it will print `[1,2,3]` regardless:

```
runfile('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Projects/xxx/var/testit.py', )
[1, 2, 3]
x = 1
main()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Am I misunderstanding scopes or is this a pycharm thing perhaps?

Comment: It works on me. I'm using Pycharm!

Comment: Where is defined `runfile()`?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik The behaviour I'm seeing matches the original question. I'm on 2018.3. The variables list does show x's value as 1 and printing x directly will print 1, but running main() still prints the original list.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oWbtCja.png 
Here's a screenshot which might make the issue more clear to everyone. 'runfile' is just a pycharm invoked command

Comment: Oh. You change the variable end of line right?.If yes your main function compile before and print then change to  `x = 1`

Comment: Looks very much like `runfile()` evaluates the entire file in a new context.